# Unzip mutiple files using batchscript and task manager

Tags: batch-file, cmd, zip, windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks

### Windows 8.1

### File Structure

Master

- sample.bat

Temp

- file1.zip
- file2.zip
- file3.zip

### Goal

To create a batchscript that handles the processing ( unzipping ) of multiple files outputting the result to a specified location (back to the "Temp" directory).

### Progress

```
@echo off

for /R "C:\Users\Isaiah\Downloads\11_Temp" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI"
)
```

### Issues

Unable to delete original zip file(s) after process completes without creating other additional copies. It is also important to mention that this script should be able to work with Windows Task Manager. Please leave reference links if possible to assist with strengthening my knowledge and for archiving.

Sincerely Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just put `del %%I` after the `7z` line? Where is the additional copy coming from? Certainly not your batch script.

Comment: No it was a work around I wrote to be able to copy and move files then del original so I was making it harder on myself. Then I was able to find this script  in another thread that gets me half way there. I believe I tried that with no resolve